# Getting warning message 1 failed to parse while running wday function of lubridate package in r

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to get day name using

```
wday(ymd("2014/09/30","%Y/%m/%d"), label = T)
```

Output I am getting is

```
#[1]  3 NA
#Warning message:
#1 failed to parse.
```

Can anyone please let me know why I am getting error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the argument `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

Just use:

```
wday(ymd("2014/09/30"), label = T)
```

Output is then:

```
# [1] Tues
# Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat
```

Comment: See the help files on `ymd`, i.e.`ymd(..., quiet = FALSE, tz = NULL, locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"),  truncated = 0)`. There is no argument for the format, because you specify the format already with the command "YearMonthDay"=ymd. The command figures out the separators by itself.